# Windows hyperV and promoting DC

Tags: active-directory, hyper-v

I have a new hyperV server joined to domain. since I do not have production VM configured on the new host. I thought of using it for testing the addition of Win2016 DC in my 2008 r2 DC production env.

I converted both my production DC (physical) with disk2vhd. copied them to hypervisor and spun them back on new host. Created a virtual private switch and assigned the private switch to each vm network. change IP address on DCs to same as production and deployed windows 2016 core and win10 and assigned IP address similar to production network instead of self assigned APIPA as my converted domain would not function with APIPA.

Would it be safe to install ADDservices on windows 2016 server without impacting production domain as they are all in private network but with same ip. I can see it does hit host and other guest VM in production with ping. I guess it would be save to introduct windows 2016 for test and simulate before I do it in production. On reason I have to complete the test is I still use domain.local for internal therefore I have to do a thorough test before adding win 2016 DC in production

Answer (score 0):

If network is private and has not cross with prod DC, then , yes its safe.

Yes, in the same time, if you get WIRESHARK, you will see that all VMs "talking" with each other on same HYPERV or in cluster.